# How do I fix "ssl handshake failed" with ApacheBench?

Tags: apache, https, apachebench

When I use ApacheBench to test https, the error is returned, "ssl handshake failed".

How can I use ApacheBench to test https?

Comment: Replaced `apachebench` tag with `apache-bench`, to match similar tags.

Comment: This seems to be caused by a bad certificate. AB is automatically using SSL.

Answer (score 10):

ApacheBench doesn't seem to be capable of ignoring certificate problems (at least some of them) so I wrote this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
K=200;    
HTTPSA='https://192.168.1.103:443/'    
date +%M-%S-%N>wgetres.txt
for (( c=1; c<=$K; c++ ))
do
    wget --no-check-certificate --secure-protocol=SSLv3 --spider $HTTPSA
done
date +%M-%S-%N>>wgetres.txt
```

It's not as precise as AB, but gives the idea. Does well in comparison tests.

Comment: Second date will be executed before wgets are completed, and so is useless.

Comment: You're right. I didn't remove the `&` at the end of the line. Fixed that.

Comment: It's not comparable to AB

Answer (score 6):

[httperf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf) is also single threaded, but as of today (Aug 31, 2012), it correctly handles SSL and even has a some useful additional features surrounding SSL:

> ```
>   --ssl  Specifies that all communication between httperf and the server
>       should  utilize  the  Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) protocol.  This
>       option is available only if httperf was compiled with  SSL  supâ€
>       port enabled.
>
>   --ssl-ciphers=L
>       This  option  is  only  meaningful  if  SSL is in use (see --ssl
>       option).  This option specifies the list L of cipher suites that
>       httperf  may  use  in  negotiating  a secure connection with the
>       server.  If the list contains more than one  cipher  suite,  the
>       ciphers  must  be  separated by a colon.  If the server does not
>       accept any of the listed cipher suites,  the  connection  estabâ€
>       lishment  will  fail and httperf will exit immediately.  If this
>       option is not specified when the --ssl option  is  present  then
>       httperf  will use all of the SSLv3 cipher suites provided by the
>       underlying SSL library.
>
>  --ssl-no-reuse
>       This option is only meaningful if SSL and sessions  are  in  use
>       (see  --ssl,  --wsess,  --wsesslog).   When an SSL connection is
>       established the client receives a  session  identifier  (session
>       id)  from the server.  On subsequent SSL connections, the client
>       normally reuses this session id in order to avoid the expense of
>       repeating  the  (slow) SSL handshake to establish a new SSL sesâ€
>       sion and obtain another session id (even if the client  attempts
>       to re-use a session id, the server may force the client to reneâ€
>       gotiate a session).  By default httperf reuses  the  session  id
>       across  all  connections  in  a  session.  If the --ssl-no-reuse
>       option is in effect, then httperf will not reuse the session id,
>       and the entire SSL handshake will be performed for each new conâ€
>       nection in a session.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently. As a work around I used the loadtest npm package, which has similar options as ab:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest