# Using apache bench against a webservice with a self-signed certificate

Tags: apache, ssl, benchmarking, apachebench

Is it possible to test a web service that is using a self-signed certificate with Apache Bench? By default, it will fail with `SSL read failed - closing connection`. I'm unable to find anyway to have it ignore SSL failures.

```
$ ab -n 1 -c 1 https://localhost:8080
Benchmarking localhost (be patient)...SSL read failed - closing connection
..done
```

Additionally, if this is not possible then does anyone know of an alternative tool which allows for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189993/how-do-i-fix-ssl-handshake-failed-with-apachebench

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "ssl handshake failed" with ApacheBench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189993/how-do-i-fix-ssl-handshake-failed-with-apachebench)