# Apache Benchmark HTTPS Issue

Tags: linux, apache, unix, server

I cannot get **apache benchmark** to work with my site. Whenever I issue this command

`ab https://example.com/`

I would get this output error:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1663405 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking example.com (be patient)...

SSL handshake failed (1).
27506:error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-59/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:593:
..done
```

Is this because apache benchmark cannot detect the SSL certificate properly on my local machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix "ssl handshake failed" with ApacheBench?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189993/how-do-i-fix-ssl-handshake-failed-with-apachebench)

Answer (score 8):

For **https** testing, I've used the **abs** command. It's the https pendant of ab for http.

You'll find it just alongside the ab command when you download the Apache Server http://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi look inside the compressed filehttpd-{version}\support\ folder and you'll see it.

Hopes this helps